# Connect to remote desktop via mstsc automatically via username and password

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, remote, remote-desktop

How do I connect to mstsc remote desktop automatically with username and passowrd just like Windows 7 works in Windows XP?

Comment: _From_ or _to_ Windows XP?

Comment: from win xp to win 2008 r2, but it does not matter anymore, answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Remote Desktop Connection profile with the remote system IP/hostname, username & ensure `Allow me to save credentials` checkbox is checked. Click on Save, and give a name.

Next time you try to connect to it, Windows should pick up the profile and login with the username & password and login automatically.

[image]

Comment: Oooh! A diamond! ;)

Comment: @BloodPhilia :D