# How do I stop Remote Desktop from prompting for username and password twice

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, login, windows-server-2008-r2

When I user remote desktop to connect to a Window 7 Professional computer (using win7 pro RDP)  it first prompts me for my password:

[image: Windows Security logon prompt]

after successfully authenticating there, it connects to the remote machine and prompts for my username and password again:

[image]

Is there any way to stop it prompting the second time? 
This second prompt only shows up when connecting to another windows 7 machine. When connecting to a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) this second prompt doesn't show up.

Note: removed domain and username info from the above images, a missing domain isn't the issue.

Comment: the following question does not solve the problem. It is disabled on this domain, and it effects the first prompt, not the second. http://superuser.com/questions/241605/connect-to-remote-desktop-via-mstsc-automatically-via-username-and-password

Comment: Setup the Windows 7 box for Network Level Authentication?

Comment: Check current GPs affecting the workstations: "You can also specify that a user is prompted for a password when connecting remotely to an RD Session Host server by applying the Always prompt for password upon connection Group Policy setting. This Group Policy setting is located in Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security"

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working?rq=1

Comment: have you tried "use another account" on the first dialog and entering the exact credentials on the first screen that you are using on the second screen?

Comment: @alumb Did you ever find a fix for this issue?

Comment: @Steven no. Near as I can tell, it is a difference between server and desktop versions of windows.

Comment: The difference doesn't lay in the operating System itself. It's a Multi User / Terminal thing. As far as i can remember a newly installed 2k8 R2 asks this second Dialog too. Looked AT [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742808(v=ws.11).aspx)?

Answer (score 7):

It can work to clear the credentials in the RDC connect dialog window and re-enter them. According to our server provider it is a common issue.

1. Open you connect dialog.
2. Select the computer you want to connect to.
3. Click the little blue delete link underneath.

   [image]
4. Re-enter and save you password and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 group policy settings to check:
*(they were already mentioned in comments [1](https://superuser.com/questions/712848/how-do-i-stop-remote-desktop-from-prompting-for-username-and-password-twice/1279957#comment911307_712848),[2](https://superuser.com/questions/712848/how-do-i-stop-remote-desktop-from-prompting-for-username-and-password-twice/1279957#comment911308_712848) above)*

- One on host: [“Always prompt for password upon connection”](https://www.spjeff.com/2017/09/27/fixed-rdp-requires-authentication-twice/)
- Two on client: [“Prompt for credentials on the client computer” and “Do not allow passwords to be saved”](https://superuser.com/a/606416/135260)

Remember to [do](https://superuser.com/q/604483/135260) `gpupdate /force` and [check](https://superuser.com/q/604483/135260) the actual values with `rsop.msc`.

If nothing works, consider using alternative RDP client, whith better logon automation:

- [mRemoteNG](https://serverfault.com/a/416141/154940)
- [RDCMan](https://superuser.com/a/606433/135260)

Also take a look at the following Windows Feedback Hub item: [normal](https://aka.ms/Ag4po1) or [for windows insiders](https://aka.ms/Tgu8b4) and consider up-voting it. There's a tiny chance that this would help as well.

PS. [Here](https://serverfault.com/q/877570/154940)'s yet another similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to change field "**prompt for credentials**" in file ***%HOMEPATH%\Documents\Default.rdp*** from 1 to 0

From

prompt for credentials:i:1

To

prompt for credentials:i:0

I also add to make file read only as Windows would change it back every connection

Answer (score 0):

Not reccomended, but you could always save your credentials in a RDP file.

1. Open **Remote Desktop Connection** by going to the **Start Menu**
2. In the search box, type *Remote Desktop Connection*,
3. In the list of results, click *Remote Desktop Connection.*
4. In the **Computer** box, type the name of the remote computer you want to connect to, click Options,
5. Select the **Allow me to save credentials check box**, and then click **Connect.**
6. You'll be asked for your credentials, and the Remember my credentials check box will be automatically selected.

The next time you connect to that remote computer, your saved credentials will be used automatically. To edit or delete your saved credentials, click edit or delete.

Comment: This effects the first prompt not the second. So doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Start the program **Run**
- Enter **control userpasswords2**
- Advance tab, Secure Logon, uncheck **Ctrl+Alt+Delete**

I hope this will help.
BTW I can't check this as the policy disabled my rights to edit this option.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I'm trying to run `mstsc` from the task scheduler. Adding an entry to the credential manager for the section labeled `Generic Credentials` solved my problem. Previously, I had an entry in `Windows Credentials`, but that kept getting ignored. In my rdp file, I have `prompt for credentials:i:0` and `promptcredentialonce:i:1`.